# loop through function parameters to create power point presentaion

Tags: python, syntax, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions, python-pptx

I am trying to define function to generate a power point presentation by `python-pptx`.
I have my own power point template and multiple images needed to be embedded into each slide. I used `*` to allow arbitrary number of arguments to functions.

For example, I have 3 iamges (`.png`). I want to put each image in different slides, said 3 here.
The code I tried:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

def Create_PPT(oldFileName, newFileName, *img):
    prs = Presentation(oldFileName)
    # Create the slides for images
    for image in *img:
        graph_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[9]  # 9 is the customized template I create in my oldfile.
        slide = prs.slides.add_slide(graph_slide_layout)
        title = slide.shapes.title
        title.text = image
        left = Inches(0.7)
        top = Inches(0.75)
        height = Inches(6)
        width = Inches(12)
        pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(image, left, top, width = width, height = height)

    prs.save(newFileName)

Create_PPT('mystyle.pptx', 'new.pptx', 'test1.png', 'test2.png', 'test3.png')
```

I got the error:

```
for image in *img:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Moreover, I think my code is incomplete. To loop through and add the slides, I guess I also need to add more syntax.

```
for index, _ in enumerate(prs.slide_layouts):
        slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[index])
```

However, this is not correct one. Above code just loop through to create different slide layouts. My slide layout is fixed, `9` here.
Therefore, I think what I need is to loop through `prs.slides.add_slide()`, but not sure about this since I got errors each try.

The output will be 3 slides with image on each and the title of each slide is images' name, `test1`, `test2`, and `test3`.
Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` is a list, I presume you just want to iterate through it:

```
for image in img:
    ...
```

Comment: Awesome. `title.text = image` will create a title for the images' name. However, it also includes `.png`. Is it possible to remove `.png` in title?

Comment: I got the answer, `image[:-4]`